# Are mythological TV shows going to be counted as source?

Tags: discussion, faq, sources-and-citations

Are mythological TV shows going to be counted as reliable source? I mean there are so many mythological shows I remember from past to present. Are those stories going to be counted as a reliable source for answers here?

Comment: I say we should count old television shows as source but not new shows. because new shows are completely highlighting to increase their T.R.P ratings. so they can even post something stupid which is not true. I have seen terrible false stories in new shows which made me to stop watching them.

Comment: You sir, should stop watching TV before you become like me!

Comment: @Mr.Green We may have a rosy view of old shows now, but back in their day they often took just as much artistic license.

Comment: I am also not in support for that but though to raise it in meta to clear our boundries

Comment: @Mr_Green yeah, i learned many things from the old Ramayan and Krishna of Ramananda Sagar. But then, they too had some modified stories on certain occasions. So TV shows can't be an authentic and reliable source.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to me, TV shows should **NOT** be counted as an authentic source, reason is that our daily soaps exaggerate the stories to make interesting to general public.

If you compare the shows you will get it that up to what extent they put their own stories and hence, they shouldn't be considered as a source to support your answers.

Comment: yes, i agree with you they should not be. Most of today's serials are flawed. In my view only Ramananda Sagar's Ramayan and Shri Krishna are the most authentic. But even they shouldn't be accepted as a source unless some scripture backs it up.

Comment: The shows are produced based on scripture. So find the original scripture and quote from that.

Comment: I would like to add, if the show backs up the historical correctness of their claims and do not suggest that they are a work of fiction, it should be okay. Quoting from an excerpt from History Channel is less likely to be refuted than some Star Plus daily soap.

Comment: I think we should be able to use them of an example, since they are vivid and some can understand better by viewing a clip, but *not as a source or back up* to a claim.